# How to proper set up a UIButton in SKScene

Tags: swift, uibutton, skscene, tvos, skview

I set up a UIButton in my Scene/View and the Button shows when the Scene is called by the ViewController. The problem is when I click the Button and my GameScene will be called, the Button will is still there. I think I set up the button in a wrong way.
I guess the problem is that I can't call the `removeFromSuperview()` function on the button1 in my `startGame` function.

How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated!

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class MenuScene: SKScene {


    override init(size: CGSize) {

        super.init(size: size)

        backgroundColor = SKColor.grayColor()

        let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "CourierNewPS-BoldMT")
        label.text = "Start Game"
        label.fontSize = 40
        label.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        label.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
        addChild(label)
    }


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let button1=UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(size.width/2, size.height/2, 300, 100))
        button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button1.setTitle("Unfocused", forState: .Normal)
        button1.setTitle("Start", forState: .Focused)
        button1.addTarget(self, action: "startGame:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.PrimaryActionTriggered)

        self.view?.addSubview(button1)
    }



    func startGame(sender:UIButton) {
        let gameView = view! as SKView
        gameView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.2)
        let scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
        gameView.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)

    }


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to your `button1` object with `sender` from `startGame(sender:UIButton)` method. It is the reference to `button1` in this case. And you can call `removeFromSuperview` method from it:

```
func startGame(sender:UIButton) {
    let gameView = view! as SKView
    gameView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.2)
    let scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
    gameView.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)

    sender.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Ha, that's it. Thank you so much! Oh, what if I had another Button - how would I remove them. sender.removeFromSuperview() won't work here because the other Button is not the sender.

Comment: Found the answer to the problem I posted above. I just had to define the Buttons in the MenuScene class.